# Helmet wrecked all versions of my app (even those not using helmet)

Tags: helmet.js

I am following a full stack web developer course on Udemy, building a webapp using Node and Express. After each section, I save a version of what I just completed, so I'll have a working version of the app to fall back on in case I screw something up in the next section. When I tried to use helmet I couldn't get it to work - it blocked everything (scripts, cdns, etc.). So I changed the code, eliminating the use of helmet. However, everything was still blocked. I went back to previous "helmetless" versions that worked before the introduction of helmet. But those are blocked, too! What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? Did your backup include the server configuration?

Comment: Update: I found that when I switch the LocalHost to a new port, things seem to work. So it seems that helmet may be attaching the Content Security Policy to the port and then the CSP doesn't go away after I dropped helmet. Am I onto something here or am I way off base?

Comment: By "blocked" I mean I can't use any cdns or download any images. Things like bootstrap, mapbox, cloudinary, etc. In the console I get an error saying something like "Refused to load the script...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:...."

Comment: The backup copy was nearly identical to the problematic version, the only difference being that I required and used helmet and set policies in the problematic version. I can share the code if someone things that would be helpful but I thought there might be a higher-level explanation as to what's going on.

Comment: I still haven't resolved this but I did find this video useful in addressing the original errors:
[You Tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zEjGJ335S4)

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. It's possible that the following occurred: (1) you enabled Helmet, which blocked things (2) you disabled Helmet, but your browser didn't update its cache, and is still blocking things. What happens if you try viewing your site in another browser, or doing a [hard refresh](https://www.howtogeek.com/672607/how-to-hard-refresh-your-web-browser-to-bypass-your-cache/)?